# Eclipse IoT Binding Hawkbit-Ditto-Hono

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto, hawkbit, eclipse-hawkbit

I am trying out Eclipse IoT Framework on my RP3.
On the host-side (local PC backend) I would like to bind Hawkbit with Ditto and at least Ditto with Hono. From [here](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/issues/796) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/pull/890) I can read that it is still not possible to connect Hawkbit with Ditto? Right?
If not is there a way to connect Hawkbit to hono?

thanks
ajava

---

**Update**

I think it is not already clear what am I supposed to achieve. Well, at the moment any Edge-Device can communicate and register itself at HawkBit via DDI-Api. On the other hand, these edge-devices also communicate through the chain: Hono->Ditto->App, with the backend-specific applications. This communication path is standardized by AMQP.

Now my Questions:

1. Hawkbit and Hono both maintain separately their own device/tenant repository. Fortunately, I see some efforts to merge them together [here](https://github.com/eclipse/hawkbit/pull/890). But it seems to me that it's not still part of the official release.
   Correct? If not I'm thankful for any help and suggestions, how to maintain only one repo.
2. Using Hawkbit through DDI-Api and not to be able to include it in the IoT-Chain (Hono->Ditto->Hawkbit) makes it just like a foreign body. So it would be helpful if one could also use the DMF-API of Hawkbit to connect it to either Hono or better than that to Ditto. In my opinion, it is still not possible, or did I misunderstood something here?

Thanks and best regards
Arash

Comment: Can you elaborate a little what you want to achieve by connecting hawkBit to Hono?

Comment: @KaiHudalla, thanks for your reply, I wóuld like to bind Hawkbit with Hono through AMQP Interface. Is it possible?

Comment: And what do you want to be able to do, after you have done so? What is the functionality that you want to use?

Comment: @KaiHudalla, I just updated my question, I hope it's now more clear, what I am supposed to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ad 1) You are right, they use separate repositories for their data. The PR you referred to is just a work around FMPOV as it basically tries to sync hawkBit's DB with Hono's registry. However, the only other solution I currently see is to put a separate provisioning service in front of Hono and hawkBit which takes care of provisioning tenants and devices to both hawkBit and Hono using their respective APIs.

ad 2) You are right in that there currently is no integration between hawkBit and Hono/Ditto regarding the DMF API. There is some work under way which will allow hawkBit to use Ditto as its repository but I do not know the current status of that nor when it will be available. Maybe you can ask about it on one of hawkBit's community channels?

Comment: @arashjavan could you please provide link to Hawkbit channel for this topic discussion

Comment: @Andrew you might want to refer to https://www.eclipse.org/hawkbit/community/ regarding hawkBit's community channels. In particular, you might want to join their Gitter channel ...